# Python 3, Check if epoch time is within timeframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to check if an epoch time is less than 1 day, 3 days, and 5 days. This seems to works but feels overly complex for python. Can it be simplified?

```
import datetime
feed_time = 1508522102
d1 = round((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(1)).timestamp())
d2 = round((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(3)).timestamp())
d3 = round((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(5)).timestamp())
if feed_time > d1:
    print("less than one day")
    # do something if feed_time is less than 1 day
if feed_time > d2:
    print("less than three days")
    # do something if feed_time is less than 3 days
if feed_time > d3:
    print("less than five days")
    # do something if feed_time is less than 5 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure; put the time delays in a list; loop through the list using an index.  When you find the correct output level, print a corresponding message from another list.

```
check = [datetime.timedelta(1)).timestamp(),
         datetime.timedelta(3)).timestamp(),
         datetime.timedelta(5)).timestamp()]

message = ["one day", "three days", "five days"]

for day in range(3):
    if feed_time > round(datetime.datetime.now() - check[day]):
        print message[day]
        break
```

Something like that?

Comment: I should have been more clear, its the way I'm finding d1, feels like a lot of typing for a simple thing. Sounds like this is still the best way to find a epoch time offset?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `time.now() - feed_time` and compare that to `x*24*60*60`.

If you want to account for [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) it is more complicated.